# PHP on Windows, how to run a script in the background?

Tags: php, windows, exec, popen, pclose

I've tried all these commands:

```
$cmd = "start /B php $rootPath\\$scriptName ";
$cmd = "php $rootPath\\$scriptName > NUL 2>&1 &";
$cmd = "php $rootPath\\$scriptName ";
```

With these PHP functions:

```
pclose(popen($cmd, 'r'));
exec($cmd);
```

And in all cases it does not run the script specified in the background. And the behaviour seems to change depending on whether I ran the initial script from command line or from a web server.

On command line it runs the script, but not in the background;  it waits for it to finish. How do I make it run it in the background?

And on a web server, it doesn't seem to execute it at all. I don't know how to get feedback on why (if) it didn't execute at all.

What's going on??
Thanks

Comment: That functionality is not desired in field of applications written in PHP, maybe you should ask yourself: why do you need this from PHP ? You may be looking for CRON, which could runs periodically CLI instances of your scripts. As far as i know there isn't any build-in function for this, the only way to bypass this limitation is to run process which spawns your desired background process and exits, perhaps something like `start /min` could work, or write script/program in another language which does it.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out about interesting option to solve your issue, there is [COM extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) available for windows PHP, which could be used like this:

```
<?php
$shell = new COM('WScript.Shell');
$shell->Run('php -f script.php', 0, false);
```

The VBscript `run` command spawn process of command line, the first argument is the command to be executed, the second is window style of that command line where 0 = hide window, the third 'false' is to not wait for return.

I do not have windows, so haven't tested it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this now then. In case it doesnt work, could you recommend, then, any other ways of doing this? I need to periodically run a script that populates a database with data fetched from an API and PHP seemed like the best way to do it

Comment: It didn't work :( it raises an exception with no description

Comment: @Jodes Do you have error reporting enabled or error log file configured/checked ? Exception without description is really weird, almost indicating internal bug. Do you have php available in PATH env variable ? If you don't add it or provide absolute path to your php.exe. That is exactly the case which CRON solves, in case of windows there is "Task Scheduler" alternative. Or you can run your script as daemon at system start.

Comment: yes I have my own error handling code which echos and logs exceptions etc. And I do have PHP in my PATH env variable. Thanks for your help. I'll look into task scheduler